# Compare string between 2 string values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my script in SQL Server:

```
declare @From varchar='280'
declare @To varchar='289'
declare @Cnt int = 0

if LEFT('2810',3) BETWEEN @From AND @To
begin
    print('Hi')
end
else
begin
    print('Bye')
end
```

I know that '281' is between '280' and '289'

But this script always returns 'Bye' when it should return 'Hi'.

This script is a sample of bigger script which can have values such as 'T39', 'K92'

So I cannot use it as numeric 280 and 289.

How to compare string between 2 string values?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always define the length of a `(n)varchar`:

```
declare @From varchar(10)='280'
declare @To varchar(10)='289'
declare @Cnt int = 0

if LEFT('2810',3) BETWEEN @From AND @To
begin
    print('Hi')
end
else
begin
    print('Bye')
end
```

**Returns**

```
Hi
```

**Without the length**

```
declare @From varchar='280'
Select @From
```

**Returns**

```
2
```

Comment: . . . What if you compare `8` withing the range of `8 - 10`. This will print buy. Here string comparisons will fail.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Yes clearly, but string ranging is very common as in product ranges and/or significant digits.

Comment: @YogeshSharma You just have to ensure same length of strings - pad left with zeroes (09 is between 08 and 10) (or explain to customer that 11 comes before 2 :)). OP case is a bit different, but seems that all strings to compare are three symbols long anyway.